# Hexadecimal to binary to decimal GUI

Tags: java, swing, binary, hex, converters

I'm trying to make a GUI for this.  Basically you press a button and you convert the hexadecimal to a binary and decimal.  I feel like I'm getting close with my codes.  I created a drive class and a panel class so far.  I'm trying to create methods in my panel class that will convert hexadecimal to binary and a hexadecimal to a decimal.  I keep getting errors though, and I'm not sure why.  I've been following my other codes, but I've been struggling getting these methods at the bottom of the panel class.  I'll show you my classes so far.

Driver class:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;


public class DriverConverter {

    //--------------------------------------------------------
    // GUI for Converter
    //--------------------------------------------------------
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame ("Hexadecimal to Binary and Decimal.");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);   
    frame.getContentPane().add(new ConverterPanel());
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);

    }
}
```

Here's my panel class:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.InputMethodListener;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.text.NumberFormat;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class ConverterPanel extends JPanel {
    private JLabel[] binary;
    private JLabel decimal;
    private JLabel inputLabel, outputLabel, resultLabel, totalLabel, totalLabel2;
    private JButton BinaryConvert, DecimalConvert;
    private JTextField hexString;
    private Font convertFont;
    private double total;


    //-------------------------------------------------------------
    // Main GUI
    //-------------------------------------------------------------

    public ConverterPanel() {

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400,300));

        hexString =  new JTextField();
        //hexadecimal.addActionListener(new ConvertListener());
        add(hexString);


        JLabel converterName = new JLabel ("Hexadecimal Converter");
        JPanel panelName = new JPanel();
        panelName.add(converterName);
        add(panelName, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        JPanel totalPanel = new JPanel();
        totalPanel.add(new JLabel ("Binary"));
        totalLabel = new JLabel ("------");
        totalPanel.add(totalLabel);
        add(totalPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        JPanel totalPanel2 = new JPanel();
        totalPanel2.add(new JLabel ("Decimal"));
        totalLabel2 = new JLabel ("------");
        totalPanel2.add(totalLabel);
        add(totalPanel2, BorderLayout.EAST);


    }

    // -------------------------------------------------------------
    // Equation  for Binary Conversion
    //--------------------------------------------------------------

    public void binaryConversion (double binary){

        try {
             Integer b = Integer.valueOf(hexString,16);
             Integer.toBinaryString(b);
           } catch (NumberFormatException ee) {
             ee.printStackTrace();
           }

    }

    // Equation for decimal conversion.

    public void decimalConversion (double decimal){

        String decimal = decimal.getText();
         try {
             Integer c = Integer.valueOf(hexString,16);
             Integer.parseInt(hexString, 16);
           } catch (NumberFormatException ee) {
             ee.printStackTrace();
           }



        //Integer c = Integer.valueOf("444", 16);
        //Integer.parseInt("444",16);
    }



}
```

I've been experimenting with these methods at the bottom.  I've been trying to create them without any errors.  I also tried using the getText() method for the JTextField.  I feel like I could be close with this, but there's something "off" with my logic of creating these methods for converting hexadecimal to binary, and binary to decimal.  I actually know the code in the stardard editor.  It makes sense to me in an editor because all you do is system.out.println the result.  It's getting it translated for a GUI that's causing some issues.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  I realize this post it long.  I'm just not sure where my error is.  It could be at the beginning of the panel class, or just at the end, so I thought posting the whole code would help with identifying the problem.  I'd appreciate any guidance you can give me.  And am I at least on the right track?  I've been trying hard to get this. Thanks.

EDIT:

Ok, I just ran it in JGrasp, and these are the errors I'm getting.  It runs in Eclipse tho.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: ConverterPanel
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2531)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:2774)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1663)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.getMainMethod(LauncherHelper.java:494)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:486)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ConverterPanel
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 6 more
```

Comment: if you keep getting errors, show us those errors. Also read them, because java errors generally tell you what's wrong =)

Comment: Well I use eclipse, and I can see the error before I compile, because it highlights them in red.   For the decimal conversion attempt, "decimal is highlighted red,  "getText" is highlighted red  "valueOf" is highlighted red and "parseInt" is highlighted red.  For my binary conversion attempt, only "valueOf is highlighted red.  I'll try compiling now and see what kind of error it give me

Comment: @ Mike.  Hmmm... I just tried compiling, but it didn't give me an error.  It displayed the GUI I have so far.  But, I know the actual logic is wrong because it's highlighted red.

Comment: Eclipse also has a console that will give you the error text. If you haven't been looking at that, make sure to turn that on and then read the javac error output

Comment: @ mike.  For some reason, it's not showing the errors in the console.  But I do see something in the "problems" section  Here's one 

Description Resource Path Location Type
The method valueOf(String, int) in the type Integer is not applicable for the arguments (JTextField, int) ConverterPanel.java line 89 Java Problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the compiler errors; 
Your method `binaryConversion` has an argument `double decimal` which will hide the `JLabel` called decimal. This means you're actually calling `getText()` on a `double`. Also you have defined the String to be called decimal, which further confuses the compiler.
Try this instead:

```
public void decimalConversion(double d) {

    String s = decimal.getText();
    try {
        Integer c = Integer.valueOf(s);
    } catch (NumberFormatException ee) {
        ee.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And in `decimalConversion` `Integer.valueOf(hexString,16);` should be `Integer.valueOf(hexString.getText(),16);`

---

Here's one way of how you can do it. This way you can enter text and press enter and it will be translated to decimal and binary and shown on the labels:

```
public class ConverterPanel extends JPanel {
    private JLabel binaryLabel = new JLabel();
    private JLabel decimalLabel = new JLabel();
    private JTextField  hexString = new JTextField();
    // omitted some variables

    public ConverterPanel() {

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 300));
        setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        JLabel converterName = new JLabel("Hexadecimal Converter");
        hexString.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                convertInput();
            }
        });

        JPanel panelName = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1,2));
        panelName.add(converterName);
        panelName.add(hexString);
        add(panelName, BorderLayout.NORTH);


        JPanel totalPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1,3));
        totalPanel.add(new JLabel("Binary"));
        totalLabel = new JLabel("------");
        totalPanel.add(totalLabel);
        totalPanel.add(binaryLabel);

        JPanel totalPanel2 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1,3));
        totalPanel2.add(new JLabel("Decimal"));
        totalLabel2 = new JLabel("------");
        totalPanel2.add(totalLabel2);
        totalPanel2.add(decimalLabel);

        JPanel south = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2,1));
        south.add(totalPanel);
        south.add(totalPanel2);
        add(south, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    }        

    private void convertInput() {

        try {
            Integer n = Integer.valueOf(hexString.getText(), 16);
            decimalLabel.setText(String.valueOf(n));
            binaryLabel.setText(Integer.toBinaryString(n));
        } catch (NumberFormatException ee) {
            ee.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

---

Here's an example of converting the text from hex to int and binary:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String string = "A3";
        int parseInt = Integer.parseInt(string, 16);
        System.out.println(parseInt);
        System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(parseInt));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
163
10100011
```

Comment: Thanks Paaske. I'll make those changes and see what happens.  This makes sense tho.  I understand it more in a standard editor.  The GUI logic still confuses me for some reason

Comment: Yes, Java Swing Programming is not the easiest thing to wrap your head around.. Here's a link to a very useful resource: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/

Comment: Thanks a lot Paaske.  I appreciate it.  I'm definitely going to look into those tutorials.

Comment: I got it to work thanks to your help.  I appreciate it.  For some reason I was banned from asking any more questions.  Idk what I did wrong...

Answer (score 2):

Hello I found several errors in your code

1.-

First, you are trying to convert a Textfield when it should be a String, you must first obtain the value of Textfield with the method `.getText()`

```
public void binaryConversion (double binary){

        try {
             Integer b = Integer.valueOf(hexString.getText(),16);
             Integer.toBinaryString(b);
           } catch (NumberFormatException ee) {
             ee.printStackTrace();
           }

    }
```

2.Second, you are trying to assign a value to a variable that has been declared as a parameter of the method, so you should change the name of the variable of method.

```
public void decimalConversion(double decimal) {

        String decimal2 = String.valueOf(decimal);
        try {
            Integer c = Integer.valueOf(hexString.getText(), 16);
            Integer.parseInt(hexString.getText(), 16);
        } catch (NumberFormatException ee) {
            System.out.println(ee.getMessage());
        } 
    }
```

And check point 1 also in this method

3.-

Third item, not found the event that causes the conversion, you should add a button for each conversion and assign a actionPerformed event.